# Executable found, but not working after 22.04 upgrade

Tags: bash, upgrade, texlive

For some unknown reason, I can't execute texlive manager anymore. However, it is found in the path:

```bsh
$ which tlmgr
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr
$ tlmgr
bash: /usr/bin/tlmgr: No such file or directory
```

Other executables in the directory work fine:

```bsh
$ which latex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/latex
$ latex -v
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)
```

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Do you have any aliases or functions by that name? `type -a tlmgr`

Comment: ```$ type -a tlmgr

tlmgr is /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr```